# How does ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection() work?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking at `ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection()` to help profile an Angular application. However, there are some things which remain unclear.

When I run `ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection({ record: true })` from the console, I get an output that looks something like this.

> common_tools.ts:64 ran 15 change detection cycles
> common_tools.ts:65 34.61 ms per check
> Profile 'Change Detection' started.
> Profile 'Change Detection' finished.
> ChangeDetectionPerfRecord {msPerTick: 34.61200000019744, numTicks: 15}

If I profile chrome and then enter `ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection({ record: true })` via chrome dev tools console, I see something like this.

[image]

So I can see that it appeared to profile change detection, but from what point?

The docs (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/enableDebugTools) show how to run the command but they do not go into much detail as to what is actually happening. I am looking for some clarity in regards to..

1. What does running `ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection({ record: true })` actually do?
2. Does `ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection({ record: true })` emulate a page refresh?
3. Does it trigger change detection throughout the whole application?
4. At what point are changes being tracked? It tells me that there were *15 change detection cycles*, but what event triggered those cycles?

Comment: This might explain part of what you want to know: [Profiling Angular Change Detection](https://medium.com/@dmitrymogilko/profiling-angular-change-detection-c00605862b9f)

Comment: @Ouroborus, I saw that article but I was still uncertain as to which components where being calculated in the timings? It is odd that it can get any timings by just running the command in dev tools. It must be triggering some event to cause change detection in whatever components it is measuring against? Possibly it is just using `ChangeDetectorRef` internally and firing a `detectChanges()` event?  This I am not sure and was hoping maybe somebody knows.

Comment: From [`common_tools.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8fd25d96142ba5bd6674ba19848b5477e9bbe861/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/tools/common_tools.ts) it looks like it forces a number change detection cycles (by calling [`.tick()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#tick) 5 or more times until 500ms has passed) and then reports the average time those took.